# Call property getter, setter, deleter - Python

Tags: python, getter-setter

I'm getting the error "Type error: 'locationTile' is not a callable object when trying to call its fdel() method. Code:

```
class GamePlayLocationTiles(object):
    """The stuff needed for game play"""
    _locationTiles = []

    def locationTiles():
        doc = "property locationTiles's doc string"
        def fget(self):
            return self._locationTiles[0]
        def fset(self, value):
            self._locationTiles = value[0]
        def fdel(self):
            del self._locationTiles[0]
        return locals()  # credit: David Niergarth
    locationTiles = property(**locationTiles())

    def __init__(self):
        self.fill_location_tiles_list()
```

different module:

```
import game_play_model

class GamePlayController:
    """perform operations on the game_play_model"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.the_game_location_tiles = game_play_model.GamePlayLocationTiles()
        self.shuffle_location_tiles()


    def shuffle_location_tiles(self):
        self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles().fdel() //this line causes the error

def main():
    the_game_play_controller = GamePlayController()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just trying to delete it as a test on accessing a private variable with a getter, setter, deleter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def shuffle_location_tiles(self):
    del self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles
```

---

The `fdel` function should not be called directly. It will be called for you when the instance tries to delete the property.

For example,

```
class Foo(object):
    def x():
        def fget(self):
            """I'm the 'x' property."""
            return self._x

        def fset(self, value):
            self._x = value

        def fdel(self):
            print('deleting x')
            del self._x
        return locals()
    x = property(**x())

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None


c = Foo()
del c.x
# deleting x
```

---

`self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles()` raises the error

```
"Type error: 'locationTile' is not a callable
```

because `self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles` calls `fget` and returns the value, `self._locationTiles[0]`. That value happens to not be callable.

You could access the property itself using  `GamePlayLocationTiles.locationTiles`, and call `fdel` with

```
GamePlayLocationTiles.locationTiles.fdel(self.the_game_location_tiles)
```

but there is no reason to do that when you can just use the statement

```
del self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles
```

Comment: This is the answer thank you. I tried deleting the [0] from the getter, setter, deleter in my code for fdel etc, so it deletes the whole list, not just one member, and it now has an error inside the fdel() method saying _locationTiles is read only. So I could get it but not delete it. Do you know why?

Comment: It's a list with the setter, getter, deleter. You cannot del a list like that. It works now. I changed it to: 

'def fdel(self):
            del self._locationTiles[0:len(self._locationTiles)]'

Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, it is simply that an instance can not delete a class attribute, (at least not that way.)

Comment: Oh, so a slightly different reason than I thought! Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 2):

The point of using `property` is that you're not using the functions directly, but use common Python idioms to get/set/delete.

In this case, you would not be calling `self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles().fdel()`, but instead `del self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles`, which would call your `fdel()` method.

The same goes for getting and setting:

- `self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles` will use your `fget`.
- `self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles = y` will use your `fset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def locationTiles():
    doc = "property locationTiles's doc string"
    def fget(self):
        return self._locationTiles[0]
    def fset(self, value):
        self._locationTiles = value[0]
    def fdel(self):
        del self._locationTiles[0]
    return locals()  # credit: David Niergarth

locationTiles = property(**locationTiles()) # This redefines locationTiles to a variable
```

I see that you have a function and a variable both given the same name. This could cause problems with the execution. When you try to reference the function locationTiles(), Python sees it as the variable locationTiles

```
def shuffle_location_tiles(self):
    self.the_game_location_tiles.locationTiles().fdel() //this line causes the error
```

Comment: Thanks. I learnt from here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/205183-a-tidy-property-idiom/